# pysnmp - get output from NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB extend script?

Tags: python, snmp, mib, pysnmp

How can I properly invoke an SNMP extend script by MIB with pysnmp 4.3?

I have this entry in the remote server's snmpd.conf file:

```
extend check_fd_wap /app/users/nagios_checks/check_fd_wap.sh
```

which in turn can be invoked by:

```
snmpwalk -t 60 -v2c -c greendale remoteserver 'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."check_fd_wap"'
NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."check_fd_wap" = STRING: { "sys_inuse" : 32640, "proc_data" : {  "ssl-mmsib" : { "proc_used" : 22, "proc_limit" : 200000 } , (...) }
```

In pysnmp I'm trying to invoke MIB `NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line."check_fd_wap"` using the sample code:

```
errorIndication, errorStatus, errorIndex, varBinds = next(
    getCmd(SnmpEngine(),
        CommunityData(community, mpModel=1),
        UdpTransportTarget((hostname, port)),
        ContextData(),
        ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB','nsExtendOutput1Line','check_fd_wap')))
)

for varBind in varBinds:
    print(' = '.join([x.prettyPrint() for x in varBind]))
```

However, this fails with the `'DisplayString' failed to cast value OctetString` error message:

```
raise SmiError('MIB object %r having type %r failed to cast value %r: %s' % (self.__args[0].prettyPrint(), self.__args[0].getMibNode().getSyntax().__class__.__name__, self.__args[1], sys.exc_info()[1]))
;SmiError: MIB object u'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.check_fd_wap' having type 'DisplayString' failed to cast value OctetString('{ "sys_inuse" (...)"" at DisplayString
```

However, calling it with the translated OID works fine (`'.1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.12.99.104.101.99.107.95.102.100.95.119.97.112'`).

```
SNMPv2-SMI::enterprises.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.12.99.104.101.99.107.95.102.100.95.119.97.112 = { "sys_inuse" : 31110, "proc_data" : {  "ssl-mmsib" : { "proc_used" : 19, "proc_limit" : 200000 } } }
```

**What is the reason for this error?**

Also, if I invoke the getCmd with the full `MIB NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.check_fd_wap` as one argument, I get the error:

```
pysnmp.smi.error.NoSuchObjectError: NoSuchObjectError({'str': 'Can\'t resolve node name ::(\'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line\', \'"check_fd_wap"\') at <pysnmp.smi.view.MibViewController instance at 0x2989638>'})
```

**Is it possible to invoke the SNMP get with the full MIB in one string?**

Comment: Did you load your custom MIB file like it described in this answer  http://stackoverflow.com/a/14635022/2807083 ?

Comment: No, since I'm not using a custom MIB, but "NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB". The MIB-to-OID translation works, what's failing is the processing of the SNMP response.

Comment: I think message `Can\'t resolve node name ::(\'NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line\', \'"check_fd_wap"\') at <pysnmp.smi.view.MibViewController instance at 0x2989638>'})` obviously says that there is problem with MIB to OID translation

Comment: And the fact all works with numeric oid too.

Comment: It probably only means the `ObjectIdentity` constructor is not being properly invoked, since `ObjectType(ObjectIdentity('NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB','nsExtendOutput1Line','check_fd_wap')))` properly translates to an OID. But that's just the second question, for which I'd be satisfied with a "No, you can't call it like that" answer.

Comment: `\'"check_fd_wap"\'` look on additional quotation mark in this string, may be this is the cause. I have no idea where are it came from in error message.

Comment: Removing the double quotes doesn't solve it. The double quotes come from the syntax required to invoke this particular MIB with snmpwalk/snmpget in the command-line.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This failure:

```
'DisplayString' failed to cast value OctetString
```

happens when pysnmp receives a response from SNMP Agent for requested OID

```
1.3.6.1.4.1.8072.1.3.2.3.1.1.12.99.104.101.99.107.95.102.100.95.119.97.112
```

(which corresponds to *NET-SNMP-EXTEND-MIB::nsExtendOutput1Line.check_fd_wap* MIB object) and then it tried to convert response value (*{ "sys_inuse" : 32640, "proc...*) into human-friendly *DisplayString* representation. At that point pysnmp failed but the exact cause is not included in your report for some reason.

I am guessing that response string sent by your SNMP Agent may accidentally exceed the length of 255 characters (which is a [constraint of DisplayString type](http://www.simpleweb.org/ietf/mibs/modules/IETF/txt/SNMPv2-TC)).

Formally correct solution is to make SNMP Agent response for that MIB object fitting 255 ASCII characters to satisfy *DisplayString* type limits.

Alternatively, you could disable MIB lookup for response values in pysnmp by passing *lookupMib=False* keyword argument to *getCmd()* function.